# Is there a way to customize the installation process of an apk?

Tags: android

So I've been looking for a way to customize the installation steps on an apk.
I would like to add an additional description on this screen. Is it possible?
[image]

Comment: probably not, doesn't seem safe or something apps would need to do

Comment: I've never even seen that screen, so it's probably coming from the app that you used to install the APK, not from the Android OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is wrong to do something like that for security reasons but,
you can make an On-boarding screen in tour app that illustrates what you want to the users and use Shared preferences to make it appear only the first time.